# Creating a function based on varying argument names in R

Tags: r, function

I want to create a function that makes functions based on varying arguments and body.

For example, take `n=2` and `a=paste0("a",1:2n)`, i.e., `a=c("a1","a2","a3","a4")`.

Then I want to create a function as follows -

```
fa = function(a1,a2,a3,a4) { 
args_fa = unlist(as.list(environment())) # catch all the arguments as a list
v1 = args_fa[1:n] # assign values to baseline function arguments
v2 = args_fa[(n+1):2*n]
f(v1,v2)
}
```

Similarly for `n=3`, I want the function to look like this -

```
fa = function(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6) { 
args_fa = unlist(as.list(environment())) # catch all the arguments as a list
v1 = args_fa[1:n] # assign values to baseline function arguments
v2 = args_fa[(n+1):2*n]
f(v1,v2)
}
```

The `f` inside the function is a baseline function (fixed) and doesn't vary. My question is how do I create `fa` based on changing `n`?

Comment: If you are passing varying arguments, use `...` instead of function overloading

Comment: Where do you define `n`? (Don't say "in the global or caller's environment" :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the ellipsis `...`, and include `n` in the argument list:

```r
fa <- function(n, ...) {
  stopifnot(length(n) == 1L, n > 0)
  args_fa <- unlist(list(...))
  v1 <- args_fa[1:n]
  v2 <- args_fa[(n+1):(2*n)]
  f(v1, v2)
}
```

Or alternatively, putting `n` as the last. This *requires* that `n` be a named-argument, it cannot be passed as a positional argument.

```r
fa <- function(..., n) {
  stopifnot(length(n) == 1L, n > 0)
  args_fa <- unlist(list(...))
  v1 <- args_fa[1:n]
  v2 <- args_fa[(n+1):(2*n)]
  f(v1, v2)
}
```

or if you are always going to have a vector or list of the arguments, then perhaps

```r
fa <- function(args_fa, n) {
  stopifnot(length(n) == 1L, n > 0)
  v1 <- args_fa[1:n]
  v2 <- args_fa[(n+1):(2*n)]
  f(v1, v2)
}
```